# How to access request parameters in Spring Boot (JSON object)

Tags: java, spring-boot

How can I have access to the request Parameter? In my example I get for `person.firstname = null`

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value= "/updateWebUserProfile", produces="application/json")
public Person update(@RequestBody Person person) //person.firstname is null here
```

http request in Angular 2

```
  updateWebUserProfile(data: any){

    let body = JSON.stringify(data); //{"firstname":"test", "lastname":"test2"}
    let headers = new Headers();

    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this._http.post(this.updateUserProfileURL, body, options)
                   .map(this.extractData)
                   .catch(this.handleError);   
}

private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body;
    if (res.text()) {
        body = res.json();
    }

    return body || {};
}
```

Comment: change the variable name to person from body and try.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Can you pls show the code line.thx

Comment: let body = JSON.stringify(data); change to let person = JSON.stringify(data); and try. I am not sure.

Comment: Add your `Person` object.